# Problem with bone

Tags: bones

I have my model and when I rotate some bone its works, but in some bone i have a problem with the rotation, like in the picture 3. Any solution?

Model: https://ibb.co/n7tnW8Z
Fine: https://ibb.co/xqbQJyh
Bad: https://ibb.co/x8GfmqM

Comment: Please host your images only on imgur [by using the provided tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and not anywhere else. Your questions and our answers might become useless, once the link to the image breaks.

Comment: could you please share your file? fill the field with the address of this page and upload: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You could use an Object Constraint - Limit Location/Limit Rotation.

Comment: It looks like you are translating instead of rotating in pic3?